# Statistical model that finds a coordinate (x,y) that minimizes the distance from a group of coordinates

Tags: least-squares, model

A example would be if I launched a 100 tennis balls in the air and plotted the coordinates of where each landed. I would like to be able to find the point in the center of all those coordinates.

I assume models exist for that sort of thing, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *point* in the center of the tennis balls is the centroid. It's computed as the mean of the x coordinates of the balls and the mean of the y coordinates.

One obvious *model* for the centroid would be the multivariate normal model: tennis ball datapoints are distributed around the centroid with some variance and, perhaps, some nonzero correlation.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for.